# Fi-Ware Synchronization installation on CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, cmake, fiware

i have problems in installing the Fi-Ware Enabler named "Synchronization" on CentOS7. After running the build-deps.bash file, I get those errors:

```
+++ readlink -f ./build-deps.bash
++ dirname /home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/build-deps.bash
+ viewer=/home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/../..
+ deps=/home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/../../../naali-deps
+ mkdir -p /home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/../../../naali-deps

++ cd /home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/../../../naali-deps
++ pwd
+ deps=/home/web/naali-deps
++ cd /home/web/tundra/tools/Linux/../..
++ pwd
+ viewer=/home/web/tundra
+ prefix=/home/web/naali-deps/install
+ build=/home/web/naali-deps/build
+ tarballs=/home/web/naali-deps/tarballs
+ tags=/home/web/naali-deps/tags
++ grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo
+ nprocs=4
+ mkdir -p /home/web/naali-deps/tarballs /home/web/naali-deps/build /home/web/naali-deps/install/lib /home/web/naali-deps/install/share /home/web/naali-deps/install/etc /home/web/naali-deps/install/include /home/web/naali-deps/tags
+ export OGRE_HOME=/home/web/naali-deps/install
+ OGRE_HOME=/home/web/naali-deps/install
+ export PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/web/.local/bin:/home/web/bin
+ PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/web/.local/bin:/home/web/bin
+ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib/pkgconfig
+ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib/pkgconfig
+ export NAALI_DEP_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install
+ NAALI_DEP_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install
+ export 'LDFLAGS=-L/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib'
+ LDFLAGS='-L/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib'
+ export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib
+ LIBRARY_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/lib
+ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/include
+ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/include
+ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/include
+ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/web/naali-deps/install/include
+ export 'CC=ccache gcc'
+ CC='ccache gcc'
+ export 'CXX=ccache g++'
+ CXX='ccache g++'
+ export CCACHE_DIR=/home/web/naali-deps/ccache
+ CCACHE_DIR=/home/web/naali-deps/ccache
+ export TUNDRA_PYTHON_ENABLED=TRUE
+ TUNDRA_PYTHON_ENABLED=TRUE
+ export BOOSTUSE148=true
+ BOOSTUSE148=true
+ '[' true = true ']'
+ boostpackage=libboost1.48-all-dev
+ lsb_release -c
+ egrep -q 'lucid|maverick|natty|oneiric|precise|maya|lisa|katya|julia|isadora|quantal|nadia|raring|olivia'
./build-deps.bash: Zeile 51: lsb_release: Kommando nicht gefunden.
+ lsb_release -d
+ egrep -q -e 'Debian GNU/Linux'
./build-deps.bash: Zeile 68: lsb_release: Kommando nicht gefunden.
+ echo 'Unknown Linux distribution, please update the build script for your distro and file a pull request, or file a bug report on the tracker.'
Unknown Linux distribution, please update the build script for your distro and file a pull request, or file a bug report on the tracker.
+ what=qjson
+ test -f /home/web/naali-deps/tags/qjson-done
+ cd /home/web/naali-deps/build
+ '[' -d /home/web/naali-deps/build/qjson ']'
+ cd qjson
+ git pull
Already up-to-date.
+ rm -r CMakeCache.txt
+ sed -e 's/CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.8)/CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.7)/'
+ mv x CMakeLists.txt
+ cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/web/naali-deps/install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELWITHDEBINFO -DQJSON_BUILD_TESTS=no
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:56 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  ccache gcc.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/web/naali-deps/build/qjson/CMakeFiles/2.8.11/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/web/naali-deps/build/qjson/CMakeFiles/2.8.11/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

All the needed compilers are installed yet, but I have no idea how to deal with the CMAKE flags. I also not found any helpful solutions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on Linux, but hopefully this helps.

There is no support for CentOS distro in Synchronization enabler build dependencies script. This was mentioned in your build log.

```
> ./build-deps.bash: Zeile 68: lsb_release: Kommando nicht gefunden.
> + echo 'Unknown Linux distribution, please update the build script for your distro and file a pull request, or file a bug report on the
> tracker.' Unknown Linux distribution, please update the build script
> for your distro and file a pull request, or file a bug report on the
> tracker.
> + what=qjson
```

If you need to build the Tundra server from source in Linux, I recommend that you use Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 distributions. But if CentOS is a must,
you need to edit the build script directly and add support for the CentOS, even though I'm not sure if the all dependencies are supported.

A good way of getting started is by have a look how Debian distro dependencies installation is done in the build script:

```
elif lsb_release -d | egrep -q -e "Debian GNU/Linux" && tty >/dev/null; then
        which aptitude > /dev/null 2>&1 || sudo apt-get install aptitude
    sudo aptitude -y install git-core python-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev \
     build-essential g++ $boostpackage libois-dev \
     ccache libqt4-dev python-dev freeglut3-dev \
     libxml2-dev cmake libalut-dev libtheora-dev ed \
     liboil0.3-dev mercurial unzip xsltproc libois-dev libxrandr-dev \
     libspeex-dev nvidia-cg-toolkit subversion \
     libfreetype6-dev libfreeimage-dev libzzip-dev \
     libxaw7-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev \
     libvlc-dev libspeexdsp-dev libprotobuf-dev \
     libprotobuf-c0 libprotobuf-c0-dev \
     protobuf-c-compiler protobuf-compiler \
     libqt4-opengl-dev libqtwebkit-dev \
     libspeexdsp-dev libprotobuf-dev \
     libvlc-dev
```

Also the build script will need to have lsb_release binaries installed in order to check what distro is being used. To install lsb_release you can try to use a following command:

```
yum install redhat-lsb
```